# React how to cleanup setTimeout outside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

If I use setTimeout and setState outside useEffect like this how do I clean it up on an unmount?

```
const MyComponents = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(null);

  const handlePress = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMyState('...');
    }, 1000);
  };

  return <button onPress={handlePress} />;
};
```

If I leave the page (e.g the components unmounts) before the time is up i get

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Save the timeout id inside a reference and use it in cleanup effect:

```
const MyComponents = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(null);

  const idRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = idRef.current;
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, []);

  const handlePress = () => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setMyState("...");
    }, 1000);
    idRef.current = id;
  };

  return <button onPress={handlePress} />;
};
```

Comment: One lil question.. without `useRef()` if we directly pass `id` to `clearTimeout()` , that would be also possible or not?

Comment: No, there will be closure on such id on first render.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @DennisVash https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lnvsp9?file=timerHook.js I have this working demo without using `useRef`. can you explain what is difference over here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no problem in this demo, try to replicate the behavior like on the question, **without** using another state to fire up `useEffect`. ie: run setTimeout inside the `onClick` callback

Comment: Basically "you cheated" and moved the timeout to another scope, it works but you introduced more complexity with more states for handling